# Substitue argument with pipes

Tags: c#, named-pipes, openh264

I am writing code that reads h264 data from socket, passes it to h264dec.exe ([openh264 decoder](https://github.com/cisco/openh264)) and then pases YUV data to YUV-RGB decoder. 
My issue is that openh264dec works like "h264dec video.h264 out.yuv".

And I don't really know how to handle arguments in code to serve them as streams.
For training purposes i've tried `h264dec video.h264 \\.\pipe\h264input` but it doesn't work, the code is as below:

```cs
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServ = new NamedPipeServerStream(Utility.DecoderOutputPipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);

Openh264.Openh264 openh264 = new Openh264.Openh264();
openh264.Start();
pipeServ.WaitForConnection();
Openh264.YUVDecoder decoder = new Openh264.YUVDecoder(pipeServ, 640, 480);
decoder.NewFrame += Decoder_NewFrame;
decoder.Start();
```

The process is:

```
public Openh264()
{
    string args;
    //args = @" \\.\pipe\" + Utility.DecoderInputPipeName;
    args = @"C:\test\vid.h264";
    args += @" \\.\pipe\" + Utility.DecoderOutputPipeName;
    openh264 = new Process();
    openh264.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    openh264.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    openh264.StartInfo.FileName = "h264dec.exe";
    openh264.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
}
```

The YUV decoder takes as an input Stream object, width and height.
The program hangs on `WaitForConnection()` and without that function, `YUV` decoder throws an exception while reading from the stream.

Is it even possible to make it work like this? Substitute arguments with pipes?

Answer (score 0):

I have read the [Openh264 source code](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/blob/master/codec/console/dec/src/h264dec.cpp) and from what I understand in this particular situation it is not possible to substitute file argument with pipe, because it tries to load whole file into memory for processing:

```c
if (fread (pBuf, 1, iFileSize, pH264File) != (uint32_t)iFileSize) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read whole file\n");
    goto label_exit;
  }
```

So I have decided to switch to ffmpeg and it works perfectly:

```
class FFmpeg
{
    Process ffmpeg;

    public FFmpeg()
    {
        String args = "";
        ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\test\ffmpeg.exe";
        args = @" -i C:\test\video.h264 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ffmpeg.Start();
    }

    public void End()
    {
        ffmpeg.Kill();
    }

    public BinaryWriter InputStream
    {
        get
        {
            return new BinaryWriter(ffmpeg.StandardInput.BaseStream);
        }
    }

    public Stream OutputStream
    {
        get
        {
            return ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
        FFmpeg.FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg.FFmpeg();
        ffmpeg.Start();
        Utils.YUVDecoder decoder = new Utils.YUVDecoder(ffmpeg.OutputStream, 640, 480);
        decoder.NewFrame += Decoder_NewFrame;
        decoder.Start();
```